# API version and IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Hello is the "old" API Version  2016-11-14  is still supported by IoT Hub ?
we are experiencing Timeout .
An IoT hub upgrade could impact the support of API version ?

Comment: Could you please add more info to the question? such as the latest documentation on the API version? any screenshots of the issue? Did you see this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/#common-parameters-and-headers

Answer (score -1):

you'll find the screenshot for the timout

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmPe2.png